# ';' expected. Unexpected token while adding Title, Description and Image in Slideshow in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to make a slideshow with Title, description and Image in android studio.
I've made a separate class for SlideItem

```
public class ScreenItem {

String Title, Text;
int ScreenImg;

public ScreenItem(String title, String text, int screenImg) {
    Title = title;
    Text = text;
    ScreenImg = screenImg;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    Title = title;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    Text = text;
}

public void setScreenImg(int screenImg) {
    ScreenImg = screenImg;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public String getText() {
    return Text;
}

public int getScreenImg() {
    return ScreenImg;
}
}
```

but when i try to add items (text, description and image) in MainActivity it gives me this error

```
List<ScreenItem> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    mList.add(new ScreenItem("Title", "Description", *R.drawable.1*));  <-- error here *
    mList.add(new ScreenItem("Title", "Description", *R.drawable.2*));  <-- error here *
    mList.add(new ScreenItem("Title", "Description", *R.drawable.3*));  <-- error here *
```

The error I'm getting is

```
';' expected. Unexpected token.
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you adding * before and after the third parameter of ScreenItem Class constructer ?

Comment: just to show that only that part has the error. Everything else works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to mention one thing here the name of the drawable or any resource file must start with an alphabet. So in this case you are named them as 1,2,3, that's why it's throwing you an error.

Rename those drawables to something else. i.e Make sure the name start with an alphabet

Happy coding

Comment: I just realised that while trying to run it. Got the same error "Resource name must start with alphabet" Thanks for your help :)